# How to passing refs to component in React

Tags: reactjs, components, refs

I have a data like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    this.a = React.createRef();
    this.b = React.createRef();
    this.c = React.createRef();
}

setValue = (data = {}) => {
    const {a='', b='', c=''} = data.constructor === ({}).constructor ? data : {};
    this.a.current.setValue(a, data => {
      this.b.current.setValue(data.b, data => {
         this.c.current.setValue(data.c);
}
}
}
}
```

How could I passing that to my customized Component like this:

```
<CusComponent ref={this.a}>
```

Here is the function to get value in CusComponent:

```
 value = function (a,b,c) {
    if (arguments.length) {
    if (a) {
      this.setState({a}, () => {
         this.value_a.value(a);
         if (b) {
           this.setState({b}, () => {
             this.value_b.value(b);
             if (c) {
               this.setState({c}, () => {
                 this.value_c.value(c);
    }
    }
    })

}
}
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass a ref down to a child component with:

```html
<CusComponent ref={this.a}>
```

Make sure you create `CusComponent` with `React.forwardRef` because that creates an argument `ref` alongside `props`. This `ref you can directly bind to anything in your child component.

```
const CusComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref}>
    {props.children}
  </button>
));
```

You can read more in detail about this in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components).

If however both your parent and child component are class components then pass down the ref to CusComponent like so:

```html
<CusComponent childref={this.a}>
```

Name the property something other than `ref`. Then you can access this ref in child component like below eg.

```js
export default class CusComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.props.childref}>Here</div>;
  }
}
```